# Altering margin in figure tag

Tags: css, html

I just began employing the figure and figcaption tag into a project, but have run into an issue I can't seem to find addressed.

Using the figure tag, the following image and caption automatically indents. I have a vertical row of additional media with h tags that looks nice and linear and want to keep it that way. The automatic indent from the figure tag throws that off in an unpleasant manner. I'm using Django, so the pictures are user submitted (matching the image size to the caption is another issue).

Is there any way, likely using CSS, to remove that automatic indent? Any insight or experience greatly appreciated.

```
                {% if story.pic %}
            <h2>Image</h2>
              <figure>
            <img class="image"src="{{ story.pic.url }}" alt="some_image_alt_text"/>
            {% if story.caption %}
                <figcaption>{{story.caption}}</figcaption>
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like browsers often adds a margin to figure. Try setting margin:0, like so:

```
figure {margin:0}
```

Comment: That works! Terrific! The caption does not match the width of the photo but that's another issue.

Comment: You can get your caption to match the image by adding display:table;width:1px; (in addition to your margin:0) to figure, and display:table-row to figcaption.

Comment: That works but it shrinks the pics to all the same very small size.

Comment: Weird, it shouldn't do that. Could you setup a jsfiddle.net of your code?

Comment: Just added a snippet with Django tags. Can easily be replaced with an image link: http://jsfiddle.net/bjAmf/