# 3D CSS Transform element positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a basic 3D card that flips when you press a button (Using the CSS perspective property on the parent and then rotateY on the two sides.

I'm just wondering how the positioning for these elements work, as whenever I adjust the font-size (in em's) the cards go further away from the actual parent.

I must have overlooked some kind of important property.

Here's the [pen](http://%20codepen.io/Tobsta/pen/gpOrOe?editors=010).

Comment: In addition to your link, you should provide the relevant part of code with which you have issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User browsers add margins to your `front` and `back` classes which is relative to the font size. To fix this, add a `margin: 0` to each of them in the CSS.

```
.front, .back {
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

If things start breaking, take note that Webkit browsers add these rules,

```
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 40px;
-webkit-margin-end: 40px;
```

and that other browsers add custom rules. Firefox adds the following:

```
margin-top: 1em;
margin-bottom: 1em;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 40px;
```

See [HTML5 <figure> margin/padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182617/html5-figure-margin-padding) and [Altering margin in figure tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419275/altering-margin-in-figure-tag).

Answer (score 2):

The `figure` elements have a default `margin: 40px 1em;`. As you increase the size of the font for the figure elements, the margin will also grow. Set the margin to 0, and you're good.

Comment: Thanks! Shows how little I know about coding!